# Gears rattling in the back

Tags: gears, noise, april-fools

My MTB is making weird rattling noises in the rear.  What could be wrong?

I'm in Australia and my bike has sram components.

Picture:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure they're authentic SRAM parts?   And not knockoff ssssssssssram parts?

Comment: Dunno, but I'd be careful dealing with it.  Those teeth can be sharp!

Comment: Looks like your bike is somewhere in the in Americas, so if your in Australia you have a bigger problem than a slight rattle.

Comment: Since when did eagles eat snakes??

Comment: The teeth are not properly indexed. And you should apply some snake oil.

Comment: Found your source.... https://www.iberobike.com/video-se-le-enrolla-una-serpiente-en-los-cambios-de-la-bicicleta/

Comment: Are you really riding with a valve adapter permanently screwed on? o.O

Comment: @Michael some people do - its a convenient place to store the adapter and it is impossible to forget.  Plus they protect the acorn nut and valve stem from most angles.

Comment: @pete - excellent post for April Fools and well done.  But the season is over so I'm closing this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because April Fools is over.

Answer (score 7):

It's not the gears that are rattling.

It's your chain!

I suspect your chain is lubricated, not by a proper thixotropic motorcycle chain lubricant, but rather by a snake oil obtained from a rattlesnake.

It isn't hard to deduce that the rattlesnake oil is causing your chain to rattle.

Answer (score 5):

As a very exprienced bike mechanic i suspect its because your eagle technology cassette is not fully compatible with snake technology chain . Next time make sure every component is 100% compatible with each other before ordering them. Combining an eagle part with a snake part is expected to have compatibility issues since avian tech is known to consume reptile tech